# Centering images php

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image in php. I'm currently using this line of code

```
echo '<img src="newimage.jpg" width="110" height="120" class="centre">';
```

However, this seems to have no effect.  I've also tried using something like this,

```
img.center {

 display: block;

 margin-left: auto;

 margin-right: auto;

}
<img src="newimage.jpg" alt="Suni" class="center" />
```

but this merely gives me a syntax error, how do I go about fixing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<div class="center"><img src="newimage.jpg" width="110" height="120"></div>';
```

and use

```
div.center {
```

instead of

```
img.center {
```

Your php syntax is correct, is the syntax error coming from php?

Comment: I tried that, its still gave me the same error,
it said:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: that is a php error, not css. maybe you need to echo the css, echo "div.center { ... }" or make sure the css is not in the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a css question

Try `margin:0 auto` in your css

Comment: +1 @Rigobert Song , that's exactly what i was going to write.

Answer (score 0):

You have a PHP error in your code, unrelated to HTML/CSS.

Are you sure you're putting all the pieces of code in the correct places? i.e. CSS should go in an external stylesheet or between `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` in your HTML.

It's generally better to put chunks of HTML code outside of the PHP sections too. Something like this:

```
<?php
//some php code
?>

<style type="text/css">
img.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

<img src="newimage.jpg" alt="Suni" class="center" />

<?php //continue your PHP code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of a centred image.  See what you think :-)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
.myImage
{
    margin: auto;
    display: block; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" alt="My Image" class="myImage"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your css:

```
div img.center {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```